# Asp.net c# web application on phonegap

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, windows-phone-7, cordova

i'm developing a web application using asp.net and c#, this application must be available on almost wp7.5 and android. I wanted to use phonegap to solve this problem but how can i use .aspx pages on it? It only supports HTML pages, not server side pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

PhoneGap allows you to use client side web technologies (HTML, Javascript & CSS) to build a native app.
It won't, and isn't designed to, work with server side technologies

Answer (score 1):

You can only access aspx pages via html requests (get, post, ajax) on html and parse and show data that comes from aspx page.

Comment: Can I do this with a javascript?

Comment: Yes. but jQuery is more easy. But dont forget, you must create a html page that calls aspx page by javascript and you'll package the html file in phonegap.

Comment: And this will automatically update each time i open the app? It's like including simple HTML code then?